# Regular expression that only accepts numbers and certain characters under certain conditions with javascript (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, numbers, character, expression

Can anyone help me with a regular expression that does the following:

- Only accepts numbers from 0-9
- Accepts only the following characters that may only appear once: "e", "," and "."
- When a period is entered, no comma may be entered anymore and vice versa
- No comma or period may be entered after the 'e'

I hope someone can help me with this, I'm not good with regular expressions myself but know they are powerful. However, if there is another method available, please let me know.
I have tried it myself through a different method. The code I have written that unfortunately does not work correctly is as follows:

```
validateNumberInput() {
  this.countPeriods = 0
  this.countCommas = 0
  this.countE = 0
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.inputValue.length; i++) {
    if (
      isNaN(this.inputValue[i]) &&
      this.inputValue[i] &&
      this.inputValue[i] != "." &&
      this.inputValue[i] != "," &&
      this.inputValue[i].toUpperCase() != "E"
    ) {
      console.log(this.inputValue[i])
      console.log(this.inputValue.length)
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(this.inputValue[i], "")
    } else if (this.inputValue[i] == "." && this.countPeriods < 1) {
      this.countPeriods = this.countPeriods + 1
      this.countCommas = this.countCommas + 1
    } else if (this.inputValue[i] == "." && this.countPeriods >= 1) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(this.inputValue[i], "")
    } else if (this.inputValue[i] == ",") {
      this.countCommas = this.countCommas + 1
      this.countPeriods = this.countPeriods + 1
    } else if (this.inputValue[i] == "E" || this.inputValue[i] == "e") {
      this.countE = this.countE + 1
    }

    //  Only accept a period, comma or 'e' once
    if (this.inputValue[i] == "." && this.countPeriods > 1) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(this.inputValue[i], "")
    } else if (this.inputValue[i] == "," && this.countCommas > 1) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(this.inputValue[i], "")
    } else if ((this.inputValue[i] == "E" || this.inputValue[i] == "e") && this.countE > 1) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(this.inputValue[i], "")
    }
  }
},
```

The problem I have is that if a period, comma or 'e' already occurs once, and I re-enter one of these characters, the character disappears in its original position and is replaced by the new one. It should be the case that if one of these characters is already entered, I am not allowed to enter these characters again

Comment: There is a bug in your code: When you parse input "abc", i=0, you delete "a", leaving inputValue="bc". Now you advance to i=1, inspecting "c", deleting it leaving inputValue="b". Now you access inputValue[1] to test for period. Program crashes. To correct, you can store inputValue[i] in a temporary variable and only use this variable in your test expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to validate if a string is a number or matches your rules is `^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+([eE][0-9]+)?$`. I found it at https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html . You can read there how it works. I only replaced ".?" with [.,]?, because you want to match a comma or a semicolon as a separator for the fractal part.
I also left out the "[-+]?" everywhere, because you do not want to match the algebraic signs (in front of the exponent or whole number).

But ...

In your posted code you tried to **delete** all invalid characters, that means transforming for example "a12a3.4x5.6e7E8" to "123.456e78".
You can also use a single regEx for that, but it would be so complicated that nobody will understand it immediately. So for that I recommend to use following three steps instead:

```
var s = "1a2.3b4.5,6e78Ee.";
var result = s.replaceAll(/[^0-9.,e]/gi, ""); // delete all characters except numbers and ,.E
console.log(result); // "12.34.5,6e78Ee."
result = result.replaceAll(/(?<=[.,e].*)[.,]/gi, ""); // delete all dots and commas that are preceded by other dots, commas or exponent.
console.log(result); // "12.3456e78Ee" 
result = result.replaceAll(/(?<=e.*)e/gi, ""); // keep the first exponent and delete all others
console.log(result); // "12.3456e78"
```

You can add a fourth step if you care for the minus sign, see code below. When you use it, do not forget to add the minus sign to the allowed character list inside the regEx in the first step.

```
var s = "-12-34.-56e-7-8";
var result = s.replaceAll(/(?<!e|^)-/gi, ""); // delete minus signs if it is not directly preceded by an E, or if it does not stand at the beginning
console.log(result); // "-1234.56e-78"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code helped me. I'm going to try to develop myself further in regular expressions, they can be really useful

Comment: Hey I had one other little question. Maybe you could help me with the following:

A minus sign may not appear more than twice in the entire string.

Before the "e", a minus sign may appear a maximum of 2 times. After the "e" this is allowed a maximum of 1x.

I partly succeeded in accepting a minus sign only once after the e. Unfortunately, I have not yet managed to accept a minus sign over the entire string maximum 2x

Comment: @AliAls I added a solution for the minus sign. If you are happy with it, then please mark my solution as accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for the good code, it helped me a lot